# How Do I Apply Validation To Form

Tags: c#

I have a requirement where I need to do Find and Replace in datagridview for multiple pages - it's working fine. The problem is, after I find a specific word and replace it and again if I click on Find and Replace button, the earlier find and replace values are gone.

How to work on it?

The code is provided below:

```
public string toFind = "";
public string toReplace = "";

private void btnFindandReplace_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f = new Form2();
    f.cmbColumnCombo.DataSource = cmbList;
    f.ShowDialog();
    toFind = f.txtfind.Text;
    toReplace = f.txtreplace.Text;

    for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[f.cmbColumnCombo.Text].Value.ToString().ToLower().Contains(f.txtfind.Text.ToLower()))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(f.txtfind.Text))
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[f.cmbColumnCombo.Text].Value =
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[f.cmbColumnCombo.Text].Value.ToString().Replace(f.txtfind.Text, f.txtreplace.Text);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Definitely not [tag:c]...

Comment: Code (and indenting!) could use some formatting, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to initialize your toFind and toReplace variables within the btnFindandReplace_Click method.

Comment: Remove the access specifiers

Comment: In that case, It's giving error stating "The name 'toReplace' does not exist in the current context.
"The name 'toFind' does not exist in the current context.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your Form object outside of the button click event handler. This will make your form global and operate on the same object.

Comment: Just because the answer contains the word "thanks" doesn't make it a "thank you" answer.